# When appending lines from a text file into a list, it sets the whole line to a string. How do I recognise different data types inside a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text-files

I am making a Pokémon game using Python 3.7.0 and I am making a save/load function using text documents. Each line inside the text file holds a string and an integer and I was wondering if there was a way to recognise that those data types already exist and append them to the list while keeping the type.

A sub issue that is cause by this is that each character in the index is treated as a separate index, rather than each part separated by the comma.

I've tried splitting each data type on a separate line and appending each one separately, then checking if it contains quotations or not but that just leaves me with the same result that I've been getting.

Each line in the text files appears like this ('name',level):

```
'charmander',12

'bulbasaur',7

'squirtle',13
```

My code to load the file into a list is as follows:

```py
path, dirs, files = next(os.walk("resources/saves")) # Read directory
fileCount = len(files)
while fileCount > 0:
    for filename in os.listdir("resources/saves"): # Iterates directory
    fileCount -= 1
    loadFile = open("resources/saves/%s" % (filename),"r")
    pokeCount = 6
    for line in loadFile:
        if pokeCount > 0:
            party.append(line.split()) # Adds first six Pokémon to the party
            pokeCount -= 1
        else:
            pc.append(line.split()) # Adds rest to the PC
            print("Game loaded!")
```

After getting the output below, I tried:

```py
for i in party:
    for j in i:
        j.replace('\"','')
        print(j) # Test if each part is treated as an index
```

However I got each character printed on a new line, as if each one was a new index, rather than the name and level be treated as two separate indexes.

I expect the appended list to look like this:

```
[['charmander',12],['bulbasaur,7],['squirtle',13]]
```

However the list I get is:

```
[["'charmander','12'"],["'bulbasaur,'7'"],["'squirtle','13'"]]
```

The numbers are being treated as strings, then the whole index is being treated as a superior string. I would like to have the name treated as a string in the first index of the sub-list, and the level treated as an integer in the second index of the sub-list.

Thanks to anyone who can understand this and who can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use a counter, simply check the length of the produces list - if it reaches 6 stop parsing the file.

You need to split each line of your file at `,` and convert the level back to a number - you read strings from your file:

*Create file:*

```
t = """
'charmander',12

'bulbasaur',7

'squirtle',13"""
```

*Read and process file:*

```
with open("data.txt","w") as f: 
    f.write(t)

pokemons = []

with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:          
        line = line.strip() # remove \n and other whitespaces
        if line:            # only process non empty lines
            try:
                poke, lvl = line.split(",")
            except ValueError:
                print("Unable to split line into 2 parts: ", line)
                continue

            try:
                lvl = int(lvl)                       # convert to int
            except ValueError:
                print("Unable to convert lvl to number: ", lvl)
                continue

            poke = poke.strip("'")               # get rid of the delimiting '

            # add to list of pokemons when all was ok   
            pokemons.append( [poke,lvl] )

        if len(pokemons) ==  6:
            break

print(pokemons)
```

Output:

```
[['charmander', 12], ['bulbasaur', 7], ['squirtle', 13]]
```

Comment: Is it preferable to say `if not line: continue` to avoid the added indentation (starting with the first `try`)?

Comment: Also: since this is Python3.7, you could avoid the entire `with ...` indentation by using `f = Path("data.txt").read_text().splitlines()` (as `pathlib.Path` includes a context handler)

Comment: @subnivean I do not mind the indentation - does it cost me anything? I only see  3.x tagged. I rather not include a dependecy on pathlib.Path and issue `from pathlib import Path` if it works without.  `f = Path("data.txt").read_text().splitlines()` needs to load the whole file into memory (wich is no problem here) but this way reads the file by line so it does work on 100000000000 lines as well - your suggestion would need huge memory for that.

Comment: Point taken on the use of `Path()` - I rarely deal with files more than 1000 lines or so. As far as indentation, I would argue it does have a potential 'cost': the mental overhead of keeping track of _why_ it's indented as one is reading the code. And as we know from the _Zen of Python_, "Flat is better than nested" - though one could debate whether that applies to data, code, or both.